# Sharing among one profile users without using team member

Tags: community, permissions, profile, permission-sets, userrecordaccess

how can i share the (Account and opportunity)records among one profiles users with out using team member option.
problem with team members is team members list is going an high.it is difficult to manage with the UI.

well i have other option "modify all".this option cant be used they can able to edit and modify the same profile users but not the other profile users.

Can any one suggest me ways how we can do this without team members option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can able to using sharing rules .Sharing rules will be available in sharing settings